# Resource ID in url

Tags: angularjs, security, url, angular-ui-router

I am developing enterprise application in angularjs. I am using ui-router plugin for routing. To get the particular resource (For example, get the customer with id "2401"), the URL would be like "www.mydomain.com/customer/profile/2401". It seems to be insecure, user can change the id directly in URL and access the resource. what is the best practice to make a secure URL in angularjs? Is there anyway to give encrypted value to secure?

Comment: That's not a frontend problem, that's a backend one. You have to be sure the user is authorised to access that resource, so you can check the ID the user is trying is owned by her/him, otherwise throw an error. But it's your backend to do this job not the Angular frontend.

Comment: +1 for what Michelem just said, usually you would use some form of session\token based authentication mechanism to authorise the user and determine what roles they have and whether these are sufficient for performing the request.

Comment: Thanks. Of course it is the responsibility of backend security layer. I am using oauth and json web token. But exact resource id in URL is not a good practice is what most of the techies' suggestion. So any form of encryption and decryptin at the backend will make sense?

Comment: Also you can encrypt ID on server side and then decrypt it back on server. Create your own custom attribute MyAttribyte inherited from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute and apply it at WebApiConfig.cs: `config.Filters.Add(new MyAttribyte());` It will **automatically** do the work.